# Inject abstract class (base activity) with HILT

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I just begin to try to use Hilt on my very simple project. For now it was all on Dagger2 but I would like to migrate to Hilt.

I have an activity :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() { 
    // SOME STUFF
}
```

And a BaseActivity like this :

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // SOME STUFF
}
```

Also, I have a class using the baseActivity to display a dialog. For example :

```
@FragmentScoped
class TestComponentImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val baseActivity: BaseActivity
) : TestComponent {

    override fun displayDialog() {
        MaterialDialog(baseActivity).show { ... 
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile, I have this error :

> BaseActivity cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

So, my question is : How to constructor inject an abstract class. I tried a lot of things but without success, like this in a Hilt module :

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBaseActivity(): BaseActivity{
        return BaseActivity() // Of course, it can't work cause it's an abstract class
    }
```

OR (like I did with Dagger) :

```
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    fun appCompatActivity(baseActivity: BaseActivity) = baseActivity as AppCompatActivity
```

Also, I'm just a beginner with Hilt so, maybe I miss something. I will keep on search :)

Thanks for your time and your answers :)

**EDIT :**

I searched on my own during few days and this seems to work but doesn't seem really good ...

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideBaseActivity(baseActivity: BaseActivity): AppCompatActivity {
    return baseActivity
}
```

But only if I put my baseActivity like this :

```
open class BaseActivity Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity()
```

However, after that, if I try to use my injected baseActivity in my TestComponentImpl like this (like I was doing with Dagger before Hilt):

```
override fun displayError() {
    Snackbar.make(
        baseActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
        "My error text",
        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
    ).apply {
        show()
    }
```

I've got another error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

So I don't think my baseActivity injection is fully well done. I'm keeping to investigate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky (*type-casting*) but should work (*untested, writing off the top of my head so feel free to let me know if something isn't working as expected*):

Create such `Module`:

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object BaseActivityModule {

  @Provides
  fun provideBaseActivity(activity: Activity): BaseActivity {
    check(activity is BaseActivity) { "Every Activity is expected to extend BaseActivity" }
    return activity as BaseActivity  
  }
}
```

The last cast `as BaseActivity` is probably unnecessary. Kotlin compiler should handle this.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. Doing it, I get :

android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or an Provides-annotated method.

Also, I search on my own during the last days and this seems to work (see edit on my post)

Comment: Are you using exactly `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)` from my answer? This part is important

Comment: Oh yes, seems to work with @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class). Sorry, I tried with @InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class). Thank you very much ! Can you explain me why it's working with ActivityComponent and not with ApplicationComponent ? Cause I understood that if it's in ApplicationComponent scope, il will be also available in ActivityComponent scope (and fragmentComponent and below in the component hierarchy --> https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html). Am I wrong ?

Comment: A particular `XyzComponent` "lives" in a lifecycle of a related `Xyz` **element**. That means that dependencies provided by this component live as long as the `Xyz` element. When another instance of `Xyz` element is created, another instance of  `XyzComponent` is spawned as well (and all its **direct** dependencies).

Hilt is smart enough to provide you with some "default" dependencies for its components. E.g. in `ActivityComponent` you can use the **related** `Activity` as a dependency (remember `XyzComponent` & `Xyz`?). That's why you can use that to `provideBaseActivity` (as the arg).

Comment: When thinking of building dependencies in `ApplicationComponent` you cannot use `Activity` because there’s no `Activities` that relate to the `ApplicationComponent` that Hilt can provide. There’s only `Application` instance (==element) you could be using to build dependencies.
On the other hand, if you wanted to use `Activity`, to build dependencies in a `FragmentComponent`, **you could do that**, because `FragmentComponent` is below `ActivityComponent` in the hierarchy (see the link you’ve provided).

Comment: So to answer directly your question from the comment: You understood correctly: "_that if it's in ApplicationComponent scope, il will be also available in ActivityComponent scope (and fragmentComponent and below in the component hierarchy_". You just misunderstood where `Activity` dependency is in the graph. It's not in the `ApplicationComponent`, it's in the `ActivityComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

@Boysteuf
@Bartek Lipinski

Facing the below error :

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements EzeApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      android.app.Activity is injected at
          com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.di.module.BaseActivityModule.provideBaseActivity(activity)
      com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.BaseSDKActivity is injected at
          com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.di.module.AppModule.provideServicePresenterPresenter(baseSDKActivity, …)
      com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.presenters.ServicePresenter is injected at
          com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.ServiceSDKActivity.presenter
      com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.ServiceSDKActivity is injected at
          com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.ServiceSDKActivity_GeneratedInjector.injectServiceSDKActivity(com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.ServiceSDKActivity) [com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.SimActivity_GeneratedInjector.injectSimActivity(com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.activity.SimActivity) [com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.ezetap.consumerpaymentsdk.base.EzeApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
```

## AppModule

```
@Module(includes = [NetworkModule::class , BaseActivityModule::class ])
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBasePresenter(baseSDKActivity: BaseSDKActivity ,ezeApi: EzeApi, @ApplicationContext context: Context ) : BaseSDKPresenter  {
        return BaseSDKPresenter(baseSDKActivity, ezeApi , context )
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSimPresenter(baseSDKActivity: BaseSDKActivity, ezeApi: EzeApi , @ApplicationContext context: Context ) : SimPresenter  {
        return SimPresenter(baseSDKActivity , ezeApi , context)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideServicePresenterPresenter(baseSDKActivity: BaseSDKActivity,ezeApi: EzeApi , @ApplicationContext context: Context ) : ServicePresenter {
        return ServicePresenter(baseSDKActivity , ezeApi , context)
    }

}
```

## BaseActivityModule

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object BaseActivityModule {

     @Provides
     fun provideBaseActivity(activity :Activity): BaseSDKActivity {
        check(activity is BaseSDKActivity) { "Every Activity is expected to extend BaseActivity" }
        return activity as BaseSDKActivity
    }

}
```

## BaseSDKActivity

```
open class BaseSDKActivity @Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity() {
}
```

## BaseSDKPresenter

```
@ActivityScoped
open class BaseSDKPresenter @Inject constructor(private val baseSDKActivity: BaseSDKActivity , private val ezeApi: EzeApi ,
                                                private val context: Context )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).